What are the advantages of using asset bundles in Blender?
On the page about the Asset Browser in the Blender manual, the last chapter discusses asset bundles. Blender 4.2 - Manual - Asset Browser
It explains that asset bundles are blend-files that do not reference any other files, and their names end in _bundle.blend.
I understand that, but I'm not clear on the advantages of using these "Asset Bundles."
Why would you choose to do it that way instead of simply marking all the data you want to add to the Asset Library as "asset" and then saving the asset library path?
Does anyone know?

When you receive a new asset file, what you usually need to do is copy/cut that file, navigate to your library, create necessary folders if needed, and paste the file.
As the documentation explains, when you have a _bundle.blend file, the Asset Browser will show this button when you open it :

Which will open the file browser to the selected library directory. So it cuts down the need to copy/paste and navigating to the library first. It's not a massive difference on paper, but it's a simple way to make it a bit faster for people who might have many libraries in many places or in a location too cumbersome to reach by hand.

Ok, that clarifies it. Thank you very much for that @Lauloque !
